# Is there a way to get an Android thumbnail between MICRO_KIND and MINI_KIND?

Tags: android

Generating thumbnails is done using the following method

```
MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(myContentResolver, origId, kind, options);
```

where the `kind` field can either be MINI_KIND or MICRO_KIND.

However, MICRO is too small and MINI is too big.

How can I get a thumbnail in between?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MINI_KIND` with sample size 2:

```
Options options = new Options();
options.inSampleSize = 2;
result = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(myContentResolver, origId, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the bitmap returned from getThumbnail() and supply it to Bitmap.createScaledBitmap().

Comment: If I scale up a MICRO thumbnail, the bitmap looks blurry (understandingly). And I don't want to scale down a MINI thumbnail because it takes a long time to load hundreds of MINI sized thumbnails.

Comment: I strongly suspect that you're not going to find a way around that problem other than to do what Android itself is doing which is to create a set of thumbnails, in your case sized to meet your needs, that persist on the device.